# CRUD app of mongoDB is running perfectly in vscode terminal but its not working in independent terminal like cmd or git bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud, node-commander

[image: In the vscode terminal its running perfectly] But in any independent terminal like Git bash or cmd its throwing error
[image: output of that in git bash]
[image: output of that in cmd]
[GitHub URL](https://github.com/Vinayak409/customer-cli)

I don't know why this error is coming, can you please help me in this ?  I tried out some solutions which are availbale on stackoverflow and on some other platforms but they are also not working.

Comment: can you show us the code for inspection??

Comment: @YeshwinVerma i linked the github url of that in question only , i am linking here also again [link](https://github.com/Vinayak409/customer-cli)

Comment: I cloned your repo and tested. Your code is working fine in my environment (arch linux). It seems like there is something wrong with your system where the .env file is not being picked up from other terminals, hence the `undefined` that is being returned in the `url` variable.

Maybe there is some kind of weird permissions issue, or some other conflict between the terminal and node? I don't know, I'm not a Windows guy. But, that is the direction I would expect you'd find the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your path first, where you want to run your command.
In first image your terminal path is `/d/web tutorials/codes/customer-cli`
and in second image terminal path is `C:\Windows\System32`

*Your project is situated in `D directory` but when you open external terminal then, the terminal is not opening in your folder instead it's open in `C directory`*

Comment: "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": "./commands.js",

i added these also in json file and added #!/usr/bin/env node in my commands.js file , it means that this app should be accessible from anywhere na in system, because it is cross platform so there shouldn't be any problem na ? but why problem is coming i am not getting that